# Import a local json file with Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, import

I have a simple `.json` file outside of my project. Like this :

```
| common
    | configuration.json
| angular-app
    | src
        | app
            | my-component
                | my-component.component.ts
    | angular.json
```

In `my-component.component.ts`, i want to import `configuration.json`. I tried `import configuration from '../../../../common.configuration.json'` but Angular just keep throwing this error :

```
ERROR in src/app/record/record.component.ts(4,23): error TS2732: Cannot find module '../../../../common/configuration.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension
```

And when i try `ng serve --resolveJsonModule`, i got this error : `Unknown option: '--resolveJsonModule'`

I can't move `configuration.json`. The `common` directory is shared with other projects.

How do you import a local json file in an Angular project ?

Comment: move your json file into assets directory. I faced same issue.

Comment: I can't move `configuration.json`, i edited my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using typescript 2.9+ (Angular 6.1+), you can import JSON modules so it will get compiled into the application. Older version don't support this so that may be your issue.

All you need to do is make sure the following three compiler options are enabled in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can import JSON modules in any TS file:

```
import jsonContents from '../../contents.json';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try by using **http** call:

```
this.http.get(`yourpath/..../common/configuration.json`).subscribe((resp: any) => {
   console.log(resp)
});
```

Comment: I don't want to expose my configuration.json file over http if possible.

Comment: If it is configuration file, it id better to have it in `environment.ts`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean but I guess you want to use the config values in your component, right?

According to this [tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/read-local-json-files-in-angular/) this can be fixed by creating a type definition file `json-typings.d.ts` in your app root folder with the following contents:

```js
declare module "*.json" {
   const value: any;
   export default value;
}
```

Comment: In my case, this option fixed the issue. A good one!